# Using COUNT For Comparison in SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: c#, count, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm attempting to combine the logic for some of my SQL queries, and I can't seem to figure out this problem. Obviously SQL Server CE has many limitations compared to SQL Server or mySQL, but surely there's a way to solve this.

I want to do a count on one table in my database, based on some parameters, and then I want to compare this value to a value stored in a column in another table.

Let's say the database is modeled like this:

`Table1`:

```
ID int
Key string
NumberInUse int
```

`Table2`:

```
ID int
OtherID int
```

Here's the necessary parts of the query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.Key = @key
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ID = Table1.ID AND OtherID = @otherID) < Table1.NumberInUse;
```

Unfortunately this query gives me this error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 4,Token line offset = 6,Token in error = SELECT ]`

So is there a way I can rephrase the `WHERE` clause of my query to utilize this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID
                  ,COUNT(*) numCount
              FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.OtherId = @otherID
             GROUP BY ID) t3
   ON t1.ID = t3.ID
 WHERE t1.Key = @Key
   AND t3.numCount < t1.NumberInUse
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's not SQL. You're missing the right operand of the second `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    LEFT JOIN ????? WHUT ?????
WHERE Table1.Key = @key
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ID = Table1.ID AND OtherID = @otherID) < Table1.NumberInUse;
```

Comment: I have corrected the original query. Sorry I chopped up a bigger query to take out the relevant parts and accidentally left that join in there.